# Accessing external static resources placed in different assembly and XAP

Tags: silverlight, prism, resourcedictionary, dynamically-loaded-xap

My prism based silveright application is divided into multiple xaps to reduce initial download size and support multi tenant application.

However, I cannot access the resource dictionaries defined in external assembly (i.e. the resource .xaml file is part of an assembly that complies/ is copied into a different xap)

Any suggestions ? because the standard syntax for accessing external resources files does not work

Comment: Can you provide more details on the type of resources you wish to share and an example of the syntax you have tried that failed?

Answer (score 0):

The book Pro Silverlight 2 in VB 2008 (p166) [MacDonald] says  "Unfortunately, Silverlight doesn't currently allow you to merge resource dictionaries, which means there is no way to split your application resources into separate files and then merge them into your application (which is possible in WPF)." I don't know if things have changed since then, but I would suggest that is the reason.